# CURL Statement with JSON yields Server Error

Tags: .net, json, curl, stack-trace

### --Updated with Stack Trace Error--

I'm struggling trying to get the following code to process correctly:

```
curl -v -u SD4FWFCF-ASD2-32FD-AF34-F34A4FA4CA34:CO0I0MM0-2349-OIJC-3409-234F098JJ3F4 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"john.doe@example.com","amountPaid":19.99,"systemName":"test-purchase","recipientPhoneNumber":"5558884321","senderPhoneNumber":"8005551234","deliveryDate":null,"paymentType":5,"scriptValues":[{"key":"fname","value":"john"},{"key":"lname","value":"doe"},{"key":"width","value":"medium"},{"key":"length","value":"large"},{"key":"city","value":"Fairbanks"},{"key":"state","value":"alaska"}]}' -k "https://api.example.com/processorder" -o output.html
```

Every time I run this, I receive a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Here is an example of that error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Sequence contains no elements
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no elements
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +371
>
>   System.Linq.Queryable.Single(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1
>   predicate) +590
>
>   Example.Web.Areas.Api.Controllers.ApiController.ProcessOrder(JsonProcessOrder
>   model) in
>   C:\Example.Web\Areas\Api\Controllers\ApiController.cs:1221
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
>   +125    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +691
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +305    Example.Web.DataController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) in C:\Example.Web\DataController.cs:180
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +20
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +469    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.3;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.3

I've tried to alter the **json**, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is throwing that error?  Sounds like it's expecting some sort of collection and not finding one.

Comment: Can we see the code for the `ProcessOrder` method?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. These methods are closed. This is all I can provide to you.

Comment: Can't tell you much then.  It looks like something in that method is trying to call `Single` on an empty sequence, but without seeing the code it's anyone's guess.  Is it possible that you left a required parameter out?  Perhaps in `scriptValues`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm figuring. Oh well. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer this question without knowing more about the methods. There is likely a call to an empty sequence as @Abe Meissler stated.